# Symfony-3.2 "Cannot access private property..."

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

I have a problem. I try to get values from DB and add their to array. Then I want to use this array for render in the template by means of Twig {{ content.language.text_logo }}. 
How can I change properties of objects in array to "public"?

This is my IndexController.php

```
<?php
namespace Seandle\HomeBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class IndexController extends Controller {
  public function indexAction() {
    return $this->render('SeandleHomeBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
      'content' => $this->getLanguage(),
    ));
  }

  private function getLanguage() {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SeandleHomeBundle:SeandleLanguage');
    $languages = $repository->findAll();
    $language = array();
    foreach ($languages as $language_key => $language_value) {
      $language['language'] = array(
        $language_value->languageLocation => array(
          $language_value->languageVariable => $language_value->languageContent
        )
      );
    }
    return $language;
  }
}
```

[This is screenshot from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7nAk.png)

Comment: Since it is referring to your entity property access, would help to see the Entity code as well. If the property is `private`, create an  accessor function, so `public function getLanguageLocation(){ return $this->languageLocation;}` could be added to the Entity and then called in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If property is private, usually it's getting with getters.

```
$language_value->getLanguageLocation();
```

And i suggest you to move this function to service, ant call service in controller. More:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html